# Magento2 How to call model function in Controller

Tags: magento2, module, controllers

I have following model in one module

```
namespace Abc\Abcd\Model\Job;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

abstract class AbstractJob extends AbstractModel
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct(
        $name = null,
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $name = null,
    }
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I've following controller in another module

```
namespace Qwerty\Abc\Controller\Adminhtml\Hooks;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

abstract class AbstractHooksbackend extends Action
{
    protected $_abstractJob;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Abc\Abcd\Model\Job\AbstractJob $abstractJob
    )
    {
        $this->_abstractJob = $abstractJob;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function setnewName($name)
    {
        $this->_abstractJob->setName($name);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting following error

```
Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $name of Abc\Abcd\Model\Job\AbstractJob.
```

Can anyone explain to me why I'm getting this error? and how can I make it correct?

**Edit:** You $name was already defined I forgot to update it here.

Comment: Please define variable before using them

Answer (score 0):

need define variable $name

You pass arguments in construct, they well used when you create object, but at the moment you use method from class .

```
namespace Abc\Abcd\Model\Job;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

abstract class AbstractJob extends AbstractModel
{
    public $name = null;

    public $context;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
       $this->context = $context
    }
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check my edit, Variable was already defined in my file but I forgot to update here.

Comment: public $name = null; and i class AbstractHooksbackend define this variable .

Comment: Same error still.